# Whatsapp video format support

Tags: video, format, whatsapp

What video formats are supported in the WhatsApp for Android and **Whatsapp Windows desktop** apps (specially the later one)?

I receive the error `Video is not supported` when I drag a video file into the interface.

I've tried the following formats and resolutions:

MP4 MPEG4 480x360, 640x360
MP4 MPEG4 720P
AVI 720P XVID
AVI 720P MPEG4
AVI 480x360 xvid
avi 360p xvid
avi 320x240 avc

Comment: Are your videos smaller than 16MB? Also, which formats have you tried?

Comment: Yes, smaller. I would like an oficial document from whatsapp developers with the supported format list, but I couldn't find one after googleing a long time.

Comment: Well, we're not exactly a "find it for me" service. If WhatsApp has published their technical documentation, you have as good a chance of finding it as we do. The limited documentation WhatsApp does offer does not appear to include a list of officially supported video formats, and only notes the file size limitation. If you could tell us what format(s) you have tried to upload, it might help.

Comment: Also, do you get the "Video is not supported" on the sending side or the receiving side? Is the issue that the videos will not play inside the WhatsApp app after they've been sent/received?

Comment: I get it when I paste the video into the wpp desktop window, on windows. I did not try on my cell phone with the same video because it's pointless to me, since I want to send videos with desktop version of wpp.

Comment: Can you please get us a list of at least some of the video formats you tried sending?

Comment: yes, sorry, MP4 MPEG4 480x360,  640x360,  MP4 MPEG4 720P, AVI 720P XVID, AVI 720P MPEG4

Comment: now AVI 480x360 xvid, avi 360p xvid, avi 320x240 avc, northing works!!!!

Comment: What about MP4? Not that many devices create Xvid these days unless it is done on purpose. Others to try are FLV or MOV. I've seen others with issues with FLV files, but they report the WhatsApp servers transcode these automatically into MP4.

Comment: look in first reply: MP4 MPEG4 480x360, 640x360, MP4 MPEG4 720P,

Comment: Oh, got it. Sorry, missed there were two replies.

Comment: @FernandoSBS - You should (always) update your question to include information like that instead of submitting a comment.  Most of the time when I read information in a comment I just glaze over it, I will read a response, but I fully expect the information in the question body.

Comment: By `MP4 MPEG4 480x360`, do you mean MPEG-4 Part 2 video? or H264? What app do you use to convert?

Comment: @Mulvya how can I check that please? I am using FormatFactory app.

Comment: Use Mediainfo from mediaarea.net. Check in View -> Text mode

Comment: Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/mp41)
File size                                : 1.57 MiB
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 599 kb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf57.41.100

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : MPEG-4 Visual
Format profile                           : Simple@L1

Comment: dude do you perhaps know what settings to use on ffmpeg to encode/convert any video into Android/iOS/Web/whatsapp/Desktop compatiable video, here is my example nodejs code using fluent-ffmpeg pastebin.com/Ep6ExM3H

Answer (score 11):

I convert video to mp4 using this settings:

- codec: H.264
- resolution: 960x540 (quater of FullHD)
- bitrate: 2-5 Mbit VBR
- audio codec: aac
- bitrate: 128kbit

And it's working.

Comment: While this is a valid answer, it appears that the asker was looking for a list of formats, not just one.

Comment: codec: H.264
audio codec: aac
MP4 Can be any size

Comment: Have you tried other formats that have worked? Please elaborate.

Comment: dude do you perhaps know what settings to use on ffmpeg to encode/convert any video into Android/iOS/Web/whatsapp/Desktop compatiable video, here is my example nodejs code using fluent-ffmpeg https://pastebin.com/Ep6ExM3H

Comment: ffmpeg for the above would be something like: `ffmpeg -y -i "C:\MyVideo.mkv" -b:v 2M -bufsize 2M -codec:v h264 -b:a 128k -codec:a aac -s 960x540 "C:\MyVideoForWA.mp4"`. This conversion worked for me also, allowed me to post to WhatsApp from https://web.whatsapp.com/ on Windows.

Comment: Watch out! The AAC need to be LC. Not HE. I just tested this. I got "Video is not supported" because of HE, it was the only change that I made to video (the video stream was identical)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, no matter what video format I used, I still coudln't send videos. I think the problem lies in the audio format, I switched to aac audio format and the couple of videos I wanted to send are now working.

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer the author's question in any significant detail.