# Whatsapp doesn't support video format

Tags: video, emulator, whatsapp

I am trying to send videos to WhatsApp after dragging the video from computer to Nox player. Even though, I changed the format of the video Mp4 to Avi. Can someday help me which format for WhatsApp videos will let me send?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whatsapp video format support](https://superuser.com/questions/1163903/whatsapp-video-format-support)

Comment: I can't seem to answer this question (because I'm a new user? so please upvote) but this works for me:

`ffmpeg -i VID_20221017_121507.mp4 -c:v h264 out.mp4`

it has issue with the encodings. my original file was mjpeg encoded which whatsapp will not display inline. this re-encodes the video format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatsapp's criteria for video sending is as follows:

**Video Codecs**:

- H.264
- MPEG-4

**Audio Codecs**:

- ACC
- AC3

**Video Containers**:

- MP4

**File Size**: 100 mb maximum (note: It fluctuates +-10 mb)

Based on updated information based on these sources: [Here](https://www.macxdvd.com/mac-dvd-video-converter-how-to/whatsapp-video-format.htm) and [Here](https://www.leawo.org/tutorial/what-video-does-whatsapp-support-1372.html)

Comment: Can you provide citations for this information? Evidence?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica here you go :) Also I work with automated file sending on Whatsapp and can attest to this information.

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp supports all file formats.

The maximum file size you can upload to the WhatsApp server is 100 MB.

Your file is probably too huge, so you can try sending it over email, or using an online cloud service like Google Drive.

However, there are some limitations, that you can read about over here: https://blog.online-convert.com/whatsapp-supports-all-kinds-of-file-formats-now/

Comment: assuming he's talking about inlining a video, no, whatsapp does not at all support all file formats. It does support as a file attachment tho. Only AVI as far as I can tell, and I'm not sure why OP didn't have success with AVI other than perhaps it was converted incorrectly